# PostgreSQL - Constraint with differents data types

Tags: postgresql, constraints

In `PostgreSQL`, I need a `constraint` to control if a value(s) is/are exists. This `constraint` is applied in an `uuid[]` data type column. It must check if each values of the `array` exists in an other column of the same table, in a `uuid` data type column.

I'm able to write a `constraint` with two similar data types, but how to run the same logic with two differents data types ?

In my case: check values in an `uuid[]` `array` with an `uuid` type.

**Table**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS public.contact
(
    uuid uuid NOT NULL DEFAULT uuid_generate_v4(),    
    name character varying COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,    
    parent_uuid uuid,
    parent_name character varying COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    child_uuids uuid[],
    child_names character varying[],
    CONSTRAINT contact_pk PRIMARY KEY (uuid),
    CONSTRAINT name_uk UNIQUE (name)       
)

TABLESPACE pg_default;
```

**First constraint (parent):** Ok

```
-- Check if parent_uuid exists in public.contact
ALTER TABLE public.contact ADD CONSTRAINT parent_uuid_fk FOREIGN KEY (parent_uuid)
REFERENCES public.contact (uuid) MATCH FULL
ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

**Second constraint (children):** Incompatible types: uuid[] and uuid

```
-- Check if child_uuids exists in public.contact
ALTER TABLE public.contact ADD CONSTRAINT child_uuids_fk FOREIGN KEY (child_uuids)
REFERENCES public.contact (uuid) MATCH FULL
ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

Comment: you can create function as described in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20215724/need-foreign-key-as-array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no good way to do that.

- You cannot create a constraint like that.
- What you can do is to create a trigger function that tries to verify the condition and throws an error if it is violated. But [such triggers are always susceptible to race conditions](https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/triggers-to-enforce-constraints/) unless you use the `SERIALIZABLE` transaction isolation level, which incurs a performance penalty.

I would say that the only good solution here is to redesign and use a junction table to implement the relationship rather than an array. Then the problem would go away.

Comment: To be 3NF compatible and respect modeling standards, I undestand your speech. However this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41054507/postgresql-array-of-elements-that-each-are-a-foreign-key) describe a [patch](https://commitfest.postgresql.org/17/1252/) who provide a possible solution, do you think it's a bad idea ?

Comment: Yes, there is a patch in the pipeline, but we don't know if it will make it. Still, why? Do you think that you get better performance that way? I seriously doubt it. I'm not advocating a normalized (1NF) design here because of its theoretical value, but precisely because it will get rid of problems like this and will for example make joins over these values simpler and faster.

Comment: Understand. I will use a third table approach.